# Why does Google repo sync into headless state

Tags: git, repo

So in the manifest.xml you specify a revision for a project, say revision master for project foo. Then you

```
repo sync
```

and it downloads the master branch of project foo. But it doesn't actually check out that branch. Rather, it puts you in a headless state, somehow starting at master...? This seems rather cumbersome if my intention is to actually WORK on the synced project.

I know it can be "fixed" pretty easily but since it seems so counter-intuitive I'm guessing they had a pretty good reason for putting you in a headless state by default. I'd like to understand the intended workflow before I deviate from it, so can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A headless state" is called `detached HEAD` in Git.

In the manifest (for example, `.repo/manifest.xml`) we can see every project has `revision`. It can be a commit (`40a264de45eb035c67aa32d73c767ed7d9378ba2`), a tag (`refs/tags/v1.0`), a branch (`refs/heads/master` or `master`) or any valid git ref (`refs/changes/11/22211/1`).

`repo sync` clones bare repos to `$coderoot/.repo/projects/` and `$coderoot/.repo/project-objects`, calls `git rev-parse` in the bare repos to get the commit of `revision`, and then `git checkout` this commit in the repos under `$coderoot/` , which always results in detached HEAD. See [project.py](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/tools_repo/blob/master/project.py).

Note that the two commands are called in two repos. Suppose there is a branch `master` in `$coderoot/.repo/project/foo.git` and there is also a branch `master` in `$coderoot/foo/`. The two `masters` may point to different commits and remember that it's allowed to run `repo sync` in an existing directory. `git checkout master` in `$coderoot/foo/` will extract the wrong code. Branch names are not credible and the commits are. That's why `repo sync` always checks out a commit instead of a branch.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to download a whole bunch of repos is great. However I find the current behavior very limiting. Imagine a repo forest with a large number of related repos, each having their version of branch name: master-1, master-2, etc

Now after running repo sync you have all of the repos in HEAD detached case. Is there an option that will checkout the branch specified in the manifest file i.e. check if the existing branch with same name is tracking the remote branch or just a local branch created by i.e is not tracking the remote.

e.g.1: repo-1 master branch is master-1, has tracking branch master-1
e.g.2: repo-2 master branch is master-2, local branch master-2 which does not track remote branch

In above example script will show repo-1 in master-1 branch while repo-2 is in HEAD detached state.